# UTF8 - Hibernate/MySQL weirdness

Tags: mysql, hibernate, solaris

I have a db in production where all of my tables are using utf8 / utf8_general_ci encoding. This is basically working fine except in one scenario.

What happens is that ??? are being returned for some characters (Chinese, etc); however, they are also returned correctly for the same table but via a different criteria.

I've double checked the connection parameters from Hibernate to MySQL and they have the good charset set.

I cannot understand how this can be happening. The criteria that returns the bad characters is just a simple findById:

```
Criteria criteria = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(CalendarEvent.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
return (CalendarEvent) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

This is only happening in production on Solaris - I cannot reproduce it locally.

Comment: Well we still have the problem. None of these help

Answer (score 3):

In your connection-string have you tried

`jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname?characterEncoding=utf8`

or add JVM parameter `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` when starting your application / server

Comment: thanks Bozho, but I don't see how VM file encoding has an effect on hibernate (I will try though)

Comment: Just so that no-one accidentally copies a wrong value: The JVM parameter should actually be -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 (with a dot instead of a hyphen)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the following properties in your hibernate configuration file:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
```

Comment: Hmm we don't have the useUnicode one (the others we do). I will try.